# Sfcartesianchart frozen and built late when work with big date in flutter

Tags: flutter, charts, sfcartesianchart

I am working with Sfcartesianchart in my flutter project, I want to show one year chart, I am getting data async from server but when create chart it frozen ui because it worked in main thread, I don't find method in this library that show loading till widget built. Is there any way to show loading progress till widget create, it can be any widget which render late.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.